# Cloning a repository not locally, but in a server

Tags: github, git-clone

Let's say I want to clone a Github repo from somebody but not to my local machine, but to my Github so I can work from the Github website and push changes from there. Is this possible? I seem only to be able to "download" locally whenever I want to clone.

Comment: Are you looking for a [fork](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can fork the repository first. Then edit the forked repo, and then commit the changes on github directly.

Comment: I actually meant working on the repo ONLINE and pushing changes from ONLINE to ONLINE.

Comment: That's exactly what the answer is saying. Use the editing features of Github to make changes in your fork on the site.